# What is difference between trigger event and dispatch event?

Tags: javascript

What is difference between trigger and dispatch event in programming.
Trigger is: generating event
Dispatch is catching it?

Comment: Where are you seeing those terms? Is there some context wherein they seemed to have a distinction?

Comment: These words, like so many are overloaded.  Without context, it's not possible to easily resolve them.

Comment: Squint's question might help. Context.

Comment: More or less, yes, triggering means is raising, dispatching means catching and sending somewhereit is handled.

Comment: I am learning redux now and asking because I see that in actions which are called by user click dispatch function is used.
    //component.js
    onClick={this.props.handleLogin}
    //action.js
    export function handleLogin() {

    return function(dispatch) {

    dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST
    })
   //this triggers and event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "trigger" is usually the initiator. A "dispatch" is usually an intermediary, that is they receive a call and delegate it to some other code.

The terms are pretty fuzzy on the edges, though, as a "dispatch" call might "trigger" another event.

The opposite of "trigger" is "handler". Those are generally event receivers. There's nothing to preclude those from making other event calls, though, so a handler might be, technically, a dispatch.

A "dispatcher" is something that repeatedly triggers events often based on timers or some kind of schedule, other input events, or other factors. Any events sent by this might be considered "dispatches" or events being "dispatched".